# Изменить DLL, чтобы он не распознавался как вирус

Tags: dll

Имеется .dll-файл, однако антивирус его считает вирусом. Чем можно его модифицировать, чтобы антивирус его вирусом не считал?

Comment: сформулируйте, пожалуйста, свой вопрос нормальным русским языком

Comment: Имеется .dll файл. Антивирус его считает вирусом, чем можно его модифицировать, чтобы антивирус его вирусом не считал.

Comment: в исключение разве что добавить ;-)

Comment: Если есть исходник, можно методом исключения определить, на какой кусок кода реагирует антивирус, и попробовать разбавить его каким-нибудь мусорным кодом. Если антивирус реагирует например на вызов какой-то функции, нужно этот вызов попробовать как-то замаскировать.

Comment: исходника нет, софт довольно старый

Comment: есть такие варианты

 - сменить антивирус.
 - добавить dll в список исключений антивируса.
 - попросить разработчиков антивируса добавить Вашу dll  белый список (если софт достаточно популярный - это можно организовать).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поможет криптор(cryptor) - RazorCrypt,EXECrypt,Themida.
Мне помогло =)